# Convertir int en varchar MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estiamdxs, buenas tardes, acudo a ustedes para realizar la siguiente consulta en `SQL Server`, ¿Cómo convierto un número como **1234567** a algo cómo **1.234.567,00**?

He estado probando lo siguiente:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(1234567 AS MONEY), 1) AS VARCHAR),',', '.')
```

El problema con esto es que la salida final es:

```
1.234.567.00
```

Y yo quiero que salga así:

```
1.234.567,00
```

¿Cómo lo consigo?

UPDATE:

Adjunto información sobre mi versionado de `SQL`

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      14.0.17199.0
Herramientas cliente de Microsoft Analysis Services                     14.0.1008.227
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     10.0.19041.1
Microsoft MSXML                     3.0 4.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                     9.11.19041.0
Microsoft .NET Framework                        4.0.30319.42000
Sistema operativo                       6.3.19044
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu comentario a la pregunta está raro. Seguro que es SQL Server 2017?

Comment: y dividiste el numero por 100 primero? si es un varchar, y no tiene separadores y los ultimos dos digitos son los decimales, deberias pasarlo a numero, dividirlo por 100, y luego darle formato.. no?

Comment: esa no es la info de tu base de datos.. es la info de la ide que usas para conectar a la base de datos ;)

Comment: @gbianchi lo se, pero fue lo primero que colgué para hacer el parte completo. De todas maneras ya lo he solucionado :D

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo estaría lindo si compartes tu solución

Comment: @Alfabravo acabo de compartirla, espero se adapte a la necesidad de alguna otra persona en un futuro :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bien, he encontrado una forma de solucionarlo:

```
DECLARE @valorEjemplo AS MONEY
SET @valorEjemplo = 1234567
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), CAST(@valorEjemplo AS MONEY), 1), ',', '|'), '.', ','), '|', '.')
```

La salida es como la que quiero:

```
1.234.567,00
```

Dejo una breve explicación:

```
/*
    Primero: cambiamos la coma (,) por algo, en este caso por (|)
    Segundo: cambiamos el punto (.) por la coma (,)
    Tercero: cambiamos el algo (|) por el punto (.)
    Entonces, al convertir en MONEY el valor 1234567, al principio queda como: 1,234,567.00
    Ahora, luego de los REPLACE este queda como: 1.234.567,00
*/
```

Comment: funciona, si.. pero no esta nada bueno.. las funciones format estan justamente para que no tengas que hacer 3 replace ;)

Comment: @gbianchi Desgraciadamente, la función `FORMAT` será 10 veces más lenta que esta opción.

Comment: en serio no esta optimizada? wow.. bueno, mejor tener eso documentado...

Comment: Me gustaría que me explicaran, de ser posible, ¿Por qué FORMAT sería más lenta? Sí me lo pudiesen mostrar con ejemplos, se los agradecería

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar la funcion Format y según yo ese formato es Aleman

**de-de = Aleman,
N = Numero**

```
SELECT FORMAT(1234567, 'N', 'de-de')
```

Comment: No funciona, me sale este error: 'FORMAT' no es un nombre de función integrada reconocido.
Actualmente tengo SQL 17

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo es raro porque [format](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) está en el T-SQL de SQL Server.

Comment: aleman? aca en argentina el formato seria el mismo.. lo que me preocupa es que es un varchar y nadie esta diviendo ese numero por 100....usamos lo mismo...

Comment: Usando `SELECT FORMAT(123456789.00, 'N', 'es-ar')` también funciona y da en español jeje. Usando la variante mexicana ya no da igual

Comment: Pues no es unico el formato, por ejemplo en este caso la argentino y aleman es el mismo , como el de méxico y estados unidos

Comment: Para saber tu version de la base de datos, puede usar una consulta tal que: `Select @@version`. No tiene nada que ver con el Management Studio que muestras que como te han dicho, no es más que un cliente de administracion. (Genial, pero un cliente). Además también importa el nivel de compatibilidad de tu base de datos. Porque aunque el servidor sea 2017, tu base puede estar en un nivel de compatibilidad por ejemplo 2005 y no funcionarían determinadas funciones como `format`

Comment: Para saber el nivel de compatibilidad puedes usar `SELECT compatibility_level  
FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'NombreDeTuBase';`  [Niveles de compatibilidad](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-ver16)